# Help with 3 variable limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to do this limit:

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y,z)  \to (0,1,0)} \dfrac{zy-z-2x^2-2(y-1)^4-2|z|}{x^2+(y-1)^4+|z|}$$

For every path I can imagine, the limit is $-2$, but I don't know how to prove it (without applying the definition).

Also, I can see the $-2$ appearing because $\dfrac{zy-z-2x^2-2(y-1)^4-2|z|}{x^2+(y-1)^4+|z|}=\dfrac{zy-z-2(x^2+(y-1)^4+|z|)}{x^2+(y-1)^4+|z|},$ but other than that, I don't know where else to go.

Comment: So what is the limit of $\dfrac{z(y-1)}{x^2+(y-1)^4+|z|}$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I guess I shall prove that it is $0$ but I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: Have you not seen various 2-dimensional limits that look similar?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, but the $x^2$ throws me off a little bit, sorry.

Comment: Start off by ignoring it.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\dfrac{zy-z-2x^2-2(y-1)^4-2|z|}{x^2+(y-1)^4+|z|} =\dfrac{z(y-1)}{x^2+(y-1)^4+|z|} -2
$$
It's sufficient to determine if
$$
    \lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,1,0)} \frac{z(y-1)}{x^2+(y-1)^4+|z|}
$$
exists. Just to be cleaner, let's set $u=x$, $v=y-1$ and $w=z$. We are down to
$$
    \lim_{(u,v,w) \to (0,0,0)} \frac{vw}{u^2+v^4+|w|}
$$
In situations like these, when you have a quotient and both numerator and denominator tend to zero, it helps to look at the degree of each. Can you approach the origin along a rational curve that makes the degrees match?

Try $u=0$, $v=t$, and $w=t^3$. Then $$ \frac{vw}{u^2 + v^4 + |w|} = \frac{t^4}{t^4 + |t^3|} $$ The limit of the right-hand side as $t\to 0$ is 1.

On the other hand, we could try $u=0$, $v=0$, and $w=t$. Then
$$
    \frac{vw}{u^2 + v^4 + |w|} = \frac{0}{|t|} = 0
$$
The limit of the right-hand side is $0$.

Since the limits along these two paths are different, the two-variable limit does not exist.